# Wrong path when trying to open a batch file via vba

Tags: excel, vba, path

I want to open a batch file via vba. This always was no problem but lately the path is not correct.

The path is always:

C:\Users\ [username] \Documents>

The batch file itself seems to be found because the code is correctly passed through:

e.g. C:\Users[username]\Documents>echo ...

I tried with absolute and with relative path. Both leads to the same problem.

```
pathDir = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info").Range("B1").Value

...

functionPath = pathDir & "\" & paramFunction & ".bat"
Call ShellExecute(0, "open", functionPath, paramECU & " " & paramBackend & " " & paramVIN, "", SW_SHOW)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the value of Cell B1?

Comment: do you mean `C:\Users\[username]\Documents` ? (it looks like you are missing a backslash)

Comment: its the path to the excel file and the batch file which is in the same directory: C:\Unterlagen\Tools\

Comment: yes there is a backslash (i made some spaces now so you see them here)

Comment: if it has a backslash at the end, and you are adding another one in your code (which you are) then that makes the path invalid.

Comment: a sorry.. now i understand you: the path is C:\Unterlagen\Tools - there is no backslash at the end

Comment: add this and then check your immediate window `debug.print pathDir & "\" & paramFunction & ".bat"`

Comment: when doing this the windows explorer is opened with the documents folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default shell path of excel is

> C:\Users[username]\Documents

So, in vba you can check by using the code

```
msgbox CurDir
```

If you need to change path of shell, the command is

```
ChDir "C:\Desire Path"
```

In case of you is

```
ChDir pathDir
```

If the path is in other drive (not C:) you should change drive before change directory. For example drive D:.

```
ChDrive "D"
ChDir "D:\Desire Path"
```

then call ShellExecute without prefix path.